Vue js, "route object" type?
How do you get the actual 'route object' type for a ts build.
route object
I'm following the the nuxt guide below and can't figure out how to get the Route object so I don't get the ts implicit any type warning on the to and from parameters`.
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  if (to.params.id === '1') {
    return abortNavigation()
  }
  // In a real app you would probably not redirect every route to `/`
  // however it is important to check `to.path` before redirecting or you
  // might get an infinite redirect loop
  if (to.path !== '/') {
    return navigateTo('/')
  }
})

Nuxt Guide

Wow, those docs sure are garbage. Looks like the type of to and from are RouteLocationNormalizedGeneric. The type for the middleware function itself appears to be RouteMiddleware which should also give you typing of the parameters

I ended up deep diving this last night.  No idea why I didn't just inspect the function as suggested by @phil.  Clearly, that was the smart move, which I am not.  However, my long way around investigation revealed some interesting things.

The "canonical" to grab types quickly from compensable objects that vue exposes is to use ReturnType

type Route = ReturnType<typeof useRoute>
type Router = ReturnType<typeof useRouter>
type MyStore = ReturnType<typeof useMyStore>
type Attrs = ReturnType<typeof useAttrs>
// ... ect

A full implementation would look like this:
import { useRoute } from 'vue'
type Route = ReturnType<typeof useRoute>

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to:Route, from:Route) => {
  if (to.params.id === '1') {
    return abortNavigation()
  }
  // In a real app you would probably not redirect every route to `/`
  // however it is important to check `to.path` before redirecting or you
  // might get an infinite redirect loop
  if (to.path !== '/') {
    return navigateTo('/')
  }
})


However... in NUXT this is a bad idea.  Because you should use the NUXT auto importing to take advantage of tree shaking and ssg compilation NUXT does.  The NUXT syntax sugar to overwrite a lot of this is to import manually.  So in NUXT do this:
type Route = ReturnType<typeof useRoute>

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to:Route, from:Route) => {
  if (to.params.id === '1') {
    return abortNavigation()
  }
  // In a real app you would probably not redirect every route to `/`
  // however it is important to check `to.path` before redirecting or you
  // might get an infinite redirect loop
  if (to.path !== '/') {
    return navigateTo('/')
  }
})

